# How can I force AmazonSQSBufferedAsyncClient to flush messages?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'm using the AWS SDK for Java and I'm using the buffering async sqs client to batch requests so that I reduce costs.

**When my application shuts down, I want to ensure that no messages are waiting in the buffer, but there's no `.flush()` method I can see on the client.**

Does `AmazonSQSBufferedAsyncClient.shutdown()` flush my messages when called? I looked at the [source code](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/sqs/buffered/AmazonSQSBufferedAsyncClient.java#L186) and it's unclear. The method calls `shutdown()` on each `QueueBuffer` that it has, but inside `QueueBuffer.shutdown()` it says

```
public void shutdown() {
  //send buffer does not require shutdown, only
  //shut down receive buffer
  receiveBuffer.shutdown();
}
```

Further, the documentation for `.shutdown()` says:

> Shuts down this client object, releasing any resources that might be
>   held open. **This is an optional method, and callers are not expected
>   to call it**, but can if they want to explicitly release any open
>   resources. Once a client has been shutdown, it should not be used to
>   make any more requests.

For this application, I need to ensure no messages get lost while being buffered. Do I need to handle this manually using the normal `AmazonSQSClient` instead of the buffering/async one?

Comment: I found this, which appears to be the same question, and is currently unanswered: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=122189

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With 1.11.37 version of the SDK, there is a configuration parameter just for this purpose in `QueueBufferConfig`.

```
AmazonSQSBufferedAsyncClient bufClient =
    new AmazonSQSBufferedAsyncClient(
        realAsyncClient,
        new QueueBufferConfig( )
            .withFlushOnShutdown(true)
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a method to explicitly call the flush but it is not accessible and actually I could not find any call to that method in amazon code. It seems like something is missing.

When you call shutdown on the async client it executes the following code:

```
public void shutdown() {
    for( QueueBuffer buffer : buffers.values() ) {
        buffer.shutdown();
    }
    realSQS.shutdown();
}
```

And QueueBuffer#shutdown() looks like this:

```
/**
 * Shuts down the queue buffer.  Once this method has been called, the 
 * queue buffer is not operational and all subsequent calls to it may fail
 * */
public void shutdown() {
    //send buffer does not require shutdown, only
    //shut down receive buffer
    receiveBuffer.shutdown();
}
```

So it seems like they are intentionally not calling to sendBuffer.shutdown() which is the method that will flush every message in the buffer that are not still sent.

Did you find a case when you shutdown the SQS Client and it lost messages? It looks like they are aware of that and that case should not happen, but if you want to be sure you can call that method with reflection which it is really nasty but it will satisfy your needs.

```
    AmazonSQSBufferedAsyncClient asyncSqsClient = <your initialization code of the client>;
    Field buffersField = ReflectionUtils.findField(AmazonSQSBufferedAsyncClient.class, "buffers");
    ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(buffersField);
    LinkedHashMap<String, Object> buffers = (LinkedHashMap<String, Object>) ReflectionUtils.getField(buffersField, asyncSqsClient);
    for (Object buffer : buffers.values()) {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("com.amazonaws.services.sqs.buffered.QueueBuffer");
        SendQueueBuffer sendQueueBuffer = (SendQueueBuffer) ReflectionUtils.getField(ReflectionUtils.findField(clazz, "sendBuffer"), buffer);
        sendQueueBuffer.flush();//finally
    }
```

Something like that should work, I guess. Let me know!

Comment: I think it will work but I would not recommend anyone to use reflection. Tons of issues when you start going that route.